# Get Blackberry Messenger Messaging status

Tags: blackberry, listener, bb-messenger

I want to make a BlackBerry application that has an ability like BlackBerry Messenger does.
The ability that I mean is like a Listener to get know when the message is queued, send, delivered, pending, and also read by other device.

Is there any suggestion to make that happen?

Comment: i am also looking for that please provide us any usefull information